# How to use .h file which have (this) as variable name into CPP file

Tags: c++

I have a header my.h which have following declaration of a function named as my_func.

```
#pragma once
void my_func (int *this);
```

this function is implemented in my.c

```
void my_func (int *this)
{
  printf("%d", *this);
}
```

in foo.cpp i want to use my_func

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <foo.h>
}
```

but i am getting following error  error: expected ')' void my_func (int *this);
Actually in my project **this** used/manipulated in .C/.h files many place. **this** is used as variable in those header/.c files many place.
I just took the above example for simplicity purpose to describe the compile error i am facing.

Comment: So what if it is used in many places? You only need to change one place - the header. Have you tried using a different parameter name in the header? If that doesn't help then please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does foo.h has header guard?

Comment: Please show the contents of the header

Comment: "this is used as variable in those header/.c". As stated, there is no need to change the `.c` files. You only need to change the declarations in the header file. Either remove the parameter or rename it. That's a 5 minute (or less job) with any search and replace tool. That is, in the header change `void my_func (int *this);` to `void my_func (int *);`.

Comment: I have updated code section with more clarity what is actual issue

Comment: That doesn't clarify it at all. The contents of the C file are irrelevant because nothing there needs to change. Please tell us why you can't simply remove `this` from the header file. Perhaps you think that you would also need to change the variable name in the C file - again, that's not the case. The C file does not need to change.

Comment: Thanks kalyum got it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this` is a [keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) in c++. You cannot use it as a variable.
You can simply rename it to something else in the header.

In fact, you can even remove the variable name completely. The compiler won't care. Named arguments are there to tell developers what the argument is meant to represent. It does not inform the compiler of anything.